# download websocket dll in c#

Tags: c#, websocket

Where can I download System.Net.WebSockets dll to use it

```
System.Net.WebSockets
```

Please provide for me  some links and thank you

Comment: It was added in .Net 4.5, so you'll need to upgrade to that.

Comment: There is no "System.Net.WebSockets.dll" - this namespace is in "System.dll"; however - are you after a web-socket *client*? or a web-socket *server* ?

Comment: web socket server i'm trying to do a little chat service where i can send a msg from an html page to a server

Answer (score 1):

`System.Net.WebSockets` namespace is part of .NET Framework 4.5 (it is located in System.dll assembly).